# Can't send message to SQS using Python 2.7 + boto2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, boto

My environment is python 2.7 and using boto 2.2.I am not able to send messages to my SQS queue. Could you please provide solutions?

```
import boto.sqs

conn = boto.sqs.connect_to_region("ap-northeast-1", aws_access_key_id='XXX', aws_secret_access_key='YYY')
queue = conn.get_queue('test_q')
res = conn.send_message(queue, "Sample Message")
```

I also try using the Message object but nothing sent to the queue.

```
import boto.sqs

conn = boto.sqs.connect_to_region("ap-northeast-1", aws_access_key_id='XXX', aws_secret_access_key='YYY')
queue = conn.get_queue('test_q')
m = Message()
m.set_body('This is my first message.')
res = conn.send_message(queue, m)
```

Comment: What is the contents of `res` after you try to send the message? Are you receiving any error messages?

Comment: **Side-note:** You really should use `boto3` rather than boto v2. (I'd also recommend Python 3, since Python 2 is [no longer supported](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/).)